# Two-sided LIMIT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 rows of data always in the same order. What I want to do is to limit the query to just get the 2th to 3th row.

for example a table 'food' with:

cake
pizza
chocolate
lettuce

```
SELECT * from food (what do i put here to only get the rows pizza and chocolate)
```

This should also work for getting for example the 4th to 8th row in a table with 10 rows.

Comment: You have to use `LIMIT M,N` clause.

Comment: @Kondybas why not add that as an actual answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause intended to do what you need:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM food 
 LIMIT 1,2  -- offset, count
;
```

Refer to the `SELECT` syntax manual for details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Caveat:  A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is not predictable.  Any `INSERT`/`DELETE`, even if unrelated, could change the output.